# why does my UIViewController get retained an extra time when using initWithNibName?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

I'm working on an app that has a Main view that wants to spawn a child view when a button is touched. So when I receive the button event, the MainViewController spawns the child view by calling initWithNibName and storing the ChildViewController in an ivar. I then show the ChildView by attaching an animation and setting childVC.view.hidden = NO.

This works, but I noticed that the ChildViewController was never getting released after closing the ChildView. I realized that the ChildVC's retain count went from 1 to 2 when I first access the child view. So something in the nib loading guts appears to be retaining my ChildVC again (in addition to the initial retain I expect during object initialization).

Can somebody help me figure out why the ChildVC is getting retained the extra time, and how can I make sure that it gets fully released when I want to close the child view?

Edit: here's some code, only slightly simplified. These are methods on the parent view controller.

```
-(IBAction)onLaunchChildButtonTouched:(id)sender
{
    m_childViewController = [[ChildViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChildViewController" bundle:nil];
    [m_childViewController setParentDelegate:self];  // this is a weak reference

    // m_childViewController retain count here is 1, as expected
    m_childViewController.view.hidden = YES;
    // m_childViewController retain count is now 2, not expected

    [self.view addSubview:m_childViewController.view];

    [self addTransitionEntrDir:YES];  // code omitted

    m_childViewController.view.hidden = NO;

}


-(void)onChildWantsToClose:(id)child
{
    NSAssert( child == m_childViewController, @"unexpected childVC" );

    // if child view is now hidden, we should remove it.
    if( m_childViewController != nil && m_childViewController.view.hidden )
    {
        [m_childViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        [m_childViewController release]; m_childViewController = nil;

        // BUG: m_childViewController retain count is still 1 here, so it never gets released

    }
}
```

Comment: may be show your actual code?

Comment: Showing some code would help bring A's to this Q.

Comment: updated original post with some code.

Answer (score 0):

Without code it is difficult to say exactly, but are you sure you are not assigning your `ChildVC` to a `retain` property of some other object? This would explain the unexpected `retain` you see.

Sorry for the previous answer, where I tried to convey this same message but I mixed everything up.

<del>OLD ANSWER:</del>
<del>keep in mind that the `view` property of a `UIViewController` is retained:</del>
    <del>view</del>

<del>The view that the controller manages.</del>

<del>@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *view</del>
<del>so, if you assign to it like this:</del>
    <del>childVC.view = [[xxxxx alloc] initWithNibName:...];</del>
<del>this explains what you are seeing.</del>
<del>Use instead:</del>
    <del>childVC.view = [[[xxxxx alloc] initWithNibName:...] autorelease];</del>

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm using initWithNibName to init the ViewController, not the view. Then (according to the docs) the View property will automatically get loaded from the nib the first time I access it. I am not autoreleasing the ViewController, but I do manually release it when the child view has closed. The problem appears to be that the ChildVC is getting retained an additional time, and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, the leaky ChildViewController was instantiating an object that retained a ref back to it.

The interesting part is that I wasn't simply forgetting to release this reference. I did have a call to release it, but that code was never running because it assumed that viewDidUnload would run and give me a chance to release everything, but it didn't. I put me deinit code inside dealloc instead, and it works now.

Comment: A common area this happens is when you `addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock:` to `NSNotificationCenter` inside `viewDidLoad`, with references to `self`, but only removeObserver inside of `dealloc`. Dealloc will never get called by definition because the block will retain `self`. You can make a weak reference to `self` to help get around this issue, or subscribe/unsubscribe to notifications in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidDisappear`, etc.